# Xdebug not working on PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

After hours and hours of try different things (based on other's problems) I can't get xdebug working with PhpStorm (in Chrome browser, CLI is working properly).

PHP version: 7.0.10; Using WAMP

php.ini (already checked):

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.1-7.0-vc14-x86_64.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9005
xdebug.remote_log = "c:/wamp64/tmp/debug.log"
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

PhpStorm config:

[image: phpstorm server cfg]

[image: phpstorm debug cfg]

When I run debug in PhpStorm, Chrome opens with the URL: `localhost:9005/test/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=14031` but remains "waiting" forever.

Comment: *"Chrome opens with the URL: `localhost:9005/test/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=14031`"* -- that's a completely wrong. `9005` is a xdebug port (xdebug communicates to IDE on this port) -- it should not be used in URLs -- in URL you should use your web port -- `80` .. or maybe `8080`. So if anything the URL should be something like `localhost/test/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=14031`

Comment: Check this link if you have not done it yet: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm -- it has pics and even videos.

Comment: Thank you so much LazyOne, my bad configuring the server! :)